# how to get all values if ID tags from SVG sprite into php array

Tags: php, file

I have svg sprite inserted in html before  tag with many svg icons. Each icon inside separate symbol tag.

```
<symbol id='arrow-right-long' viewBox='0 0 512 512'>
    <path .... />
</symbol>

<symbol id='bars' viewBox='0 0 512 512'>
    <path .... />
</symbol>
```

Then I output on the page like that

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="#bars"></use>
</svg>
```

But I want to have one page where I can see all my icons for reference.
How to parse svg file and get all values from id tags into php array?

Comment: its xml, just use a parser like SimpleXML, DomDocument or simular, both php and js can parse xml

Comment: like: https://3v4l.org/QPOQ5